# jQuery Plugin - How do these settings work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking at a jQuery Plugin source to see how it works, and the way the settings for the plugin are defined is new to me. Could someone please explain how it works?

```
$.fn.thePluginFunc = function(settings) {

        settings = settings || {}; // Why is it using an OR?

        var g = settings.g || -3; // How/why are the values access this way?
        var dt = settings.dt || 20;
        var bounce = settings.bounce || 0.7;
        var endVelocity = settings.endVelocity || 20;
        var stagger = settings.stagger || 200;
        var relativeToDocument = settings.relativeToDocument || false;
        var clear = settings.clear || false;
        var fallToLeft = settings.fallToLeft || false;
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is one way to check whether the object is present or not. If the object is not there default value is set**

In the above example  `settings` is an object used by `thePluginFunc` as argument if the `setting` object is present if it is not in this case it takes the `{}`.

**Same as like the below code**

```
if(settings){
   settings = settings; // if the object is there
}
else{
  settings  = {}; // set if the object is not
}
```

**or use like**

```
 settings = settings || {};
```

**the above two code snippets are same.**

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a settings object to the thePluginFunc function then the variables inside the function will be initialized with your setting, otherwise if you don't pass any object to the function the variables will be initialized with the default values like -3 , 20 , 0.7 ecc.

For example in the the first var, if settings.g ve a value g will be initialized with the external settings value, otherwise with the -3.

Using this method you can use a not complete object like this:

```
settings = {g: "abc", dt: "def"};
```

then the result:

```
    var g = "abc"; 
    var dt = "def";
    var bounce = 0.7;
    var endVelocity = 20;
    var stagger = 200;
    var relativeToDocument = false;
    var clear = false;
    var fallToLeft = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, `||` operator use for `OR` expression. Follow this behavior if first operand have `false` value [ ie. '' (blank string), `undefined`], it will return second operand value.

```
settings = settings || {}; // Why is it using an OR?
```

If you haven't pass any options, then above statement will assign empty object.

Same follows to other variable.

Hope it will give you clear idea.